# Create an ASP.NET Web Application to be an Office 365 task pane AddIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, office365-apps

Even though [C# and others are listed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984338.aspx#O365_DevOverviewDevelopmentComponents) as a possible language, all of the samples I have found show how to create a task pane AddIn using HTML5/JavaScript only.

I've already gone through all of these:

- [How to: Create your first task pane app by using "Napa" Office 365 Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554660.aspx)
- [How to: Create a basic app for SharePoint by using "Napa" Office 365 Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220041.aspx)
- [How to: Create your first mail app for Outlook by using "Napa" Office 365 Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220072.aspx)
- [How to: Create your first content app for Excel by using "Napa" Office 365 Development Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220065.aspx)

and others, and **they are all HTML5/JavaScript!** Even the [MSDN samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj220075.aspx) are HTML5/JavaScript only!

How can I have an ASP.NET Web Application talk to Office 365 so it can provide a task pane control and edit the selected text?

Comment: Seems like a subject that not many know about. Take a look at "[What if I don't get a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)" on the FAQ.

Comment: @Jesse Thank you for improving the question - much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've made it! It is not difficult. Firstly you have to use Visual Studio. When you develop directly from browser, download and open that project in Visual Studio. You can follow this way to make very easy example

1. Create HTML5/JavaScript application like in the 'How to' (first link)
2. Add new ASPX page into the Home folder
3. Open your App xml in the Solution folder
4. Here you can change Source location to new ASPX web page
5. Start application